# Android build fails always when I build using Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-android-api

When I try to build my android project using jenkins, the build always fails. But it succeeds when I'm building through android studio.

My Project level build.gradle code is given below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.5.0'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/schibstedspain/maven"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis'
        }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module level build.gradle is given below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.demoapp"
        versionName "1.0.0.6"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
    flavorDimensions "demoapp"
    productFlavors {
        localdev {
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_local_dev"
            ]
        }
        dev {
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_dev"
            ]
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            jniDebuggable false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // Android Support libraries
    def supportVersion = '28.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:$supportVersion"

    // ArcGIS
    def arcGISVersion = '100.3.0'
    implementation "com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:$arcGISVersion"

    // Square libraries
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'

    // Google lilbraries
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0'

    // Fabric
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //Circular imageView hdodenhof
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Following is the log which I'm getting.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDevDebugResources'. java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  Output:  C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\38d0f08e978f9054bdf191f5dc7a9836\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png: error: file not found.

  Command: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\d0f8b1c9646d3205e347ca7495d045a1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --no-crunch \
          --legacy \
          -o \
          D:\workspace\technician\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\dev\debug \
          C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\38d0f08e978f9054bdf191f5dc7a9836\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDevDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\38d0f08e978f9054bdf191f5dc7a9836\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png: error: file not found.

Command: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\d0f8b1c9646d3205e347ca7495d045a1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --no-crunch \
        --legacy \
        -o \
        D:\workspace\technician\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\dev\debug \
        C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\38d0f08e978f9054bdf191f5dc7a9836\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\38d0f08e978f9054bdf191f5dc7a9836\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png: error: file not found.

Command: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\d0f8b1c9646d3205e347ca7495d045a1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --no-crunch \
        --legacy \
        -o \
        D:\workspace\technician\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\dev\debug \
        C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\38d0f08e978f9054bdf191f5dc7a9836\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.close(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:56)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.aapt.WorkerExecutorResourceCompilationService.close(WorkerExecutorResourceCompilationService.kt:67)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:324)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\38d0f08e978f9054bdf191f5dc7a9836\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png: error: file not found.

Command: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\d0f8b1c9646d3205e347ca7495d045a1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --no-crunch \
        --legacy \
        -o \
        D:\workspace\technician\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\dev\debug \
        C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\38d0f08e978f9054bdf191f5dc7a9836\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doCompile(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:142)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.compile(Aapt2Daemon.kt:81)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.compile(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:170)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:37)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:28)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:71)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon$default(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.run(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:34)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:39)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
18 actionable tasks: 16 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

The build scan was not published due to a configuration problem.

The Gradle Terms of Service have not been agreed to.

To agree to the Gradle Terms of Service, include the following in your root project's configuration:
buildScan { termsOfServiceUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'; termsOfServiceAgree = 'yes' }

For more information, please see https://gradle.com/scans/help/plugin-terms-of-service.

Alternatively, if you are using Gradle Enterprise, specify the server location.
For more information, please see https://gradle.com/scans/help/plugin-enterprise-config.

Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some files are not found while build using jenkins. It might due to the user under which Jenkins service is runnning. You can try changing the user for the jenkins service by following steps:

1. Open the Administrative Tools > Services window on your Windows
   server.
2. Stop the Jenkins service.
3. Open the Properties > Log On dialog.
4. Change the service user account to the target user account.
5. Start the Jenkins service.